# HighChart flags Data load issues

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am working on drawing graphs from our data. There is no problem on drawing graph basically.  The only problem is that the flags information is not loaded and located on the graph lines.  Let me give you the issues on it.

1. Data cannot be brought to the graph if it has over 900 numbers of items.
2. One data might have more than 4000 items.
3. Instead using one big data, I tried to spilt one data into small pieces of data.  Each piece of data has 800 items, and they are intended being loaded on the graph sequentially.  However, this process was not easily done well.  Sometime the graph module cannot load every piece exactly.  Moreover, this process take much time than using one data.

I wonder whether an appropriate way to load flag data which contains many items exits or not.

```
$(function() {
    var report_data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url:"/apps.chart/chart.reportShort",
        data:"callback=?&report_type=CO&business_code=005930",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(report){
            report_data = report;
        }
    });

    $.getJSON('/apps.chart/chart.chartList?callback=?&report_type=CO&business_code=005930', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#chartView').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                plotBorderColor: '#346691',
                plotBorderWidth: 2,
                height: 600
            },
            rangeSelector : {
                inputEnabled: $('#chartView').width() > 400,
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'SK'
            },

            tooltip: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%Y년 %m월 %d일'
                },
                style: {
                    width: '300px'
                },
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%m.%d',
                    week: '%m.%d',
                    month: '%Y.%m',
                    year: '%Y'
                }
            },
            yAxis : {
                labels : {
                    formatter : function() {
                        var n = this.value;
                        var reg = /(^[+-]?\d+)(\d{3})/;
                        n += '';
                        while (reg.test(n))
                        n = n.replace(reg, '$1' + ',' + '$2');

                        return n;
                    },
                    align : 'left',
                    x : 5,
                    y : 2
                },
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                minPadding: 0,
                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                title : {
                    text : '금액(원)',
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name : '종가',
                data : data,
                id : 'dataseries',
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                shadow : true,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 0
                }
            }
            // the event marker flags
            ,{
                type : 'flags',
                data : report_data,
                style: {
                    cursor: 'hand'
                },
                onSeries : 'dataseries',
                shape : 'circlepin',
                width : 15,
                height : 15,
                color : '#121212'
            }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you call two ajax asynchronously, so I advice you to next ajax insiae first callback and then initialise chart.